# Creating a Round Button in WPF7

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, button

I'm attempting to get a round play button like the one in the music hub (i.e. circle with a triancle in it.
I've defined two resources in App.Xaml

- PlayIcon - The path that defines the icon
- RoundButton - A round button pulled from [Alex Yakhnin's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/13/creating-round-button-for-wp7-part-1.aspx)

The button renders and the path renders outside of the button but I can't get the icon to render inside the button. I'm fairly sure I've missed something simple/stupid but I can't see what's wrong. I've included a simple page.xaml and my app.xaml below

**Page Xaml**

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="800"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
Orientation="Portrait"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">     
    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Button Style="{StaticResource RoundButton}" Width="68" Height="68" Content="{StaticResource PlayIcon}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**App.Xaml**

```
<!--Application Resources-->
<Application.Resources>
    <Path x:Key="PlayIcon" Data="F1M84.127,709.4629L70.558,719.8039L70.558,699.2159z" Fill="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" Stretch="Fill" RenderTransformOrigin="-5.643,0.412" UseLayoutRounding="False" />
    <Style x:Key="RoundButton" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilySemiBold}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeMediumLarge}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3,10,5"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PhoneDisabledBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBackground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Transparent"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="ButtonBackground" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="33" Margin="{StaticResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">                               
                              <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                <ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                                         <ScaleTransform x:Name="buttonScale" />
                                </ContentControl.RenderTransform>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>

<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Answer (score 6):

You could save yourself some time and effort and use the `RoundButton` control from the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/), which is also theme friendly. That said, I think the problem may be that your're trying to use a Path in multiple places, which I don't think you can do in Silverlight for WP7 (happy to be proved wrong here). So, you could just use the play icon that comes with the Windows Phone Toolkit instead.

Comment: Ooh, that toolkit looks great!

Answer (score 0):

When images don't show up for me, it is usually because I forgot to set it's Build Action in the properties dialog to Content and Do not copy.

You right click on the image in Solution Explorer to get to the porperties dialog I am speaking of